# how to upload image and video using ajax in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, video, upload

How to save image and video with other details of the data at the same time using ajax? Thank you.

Comment: I think this post will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792856/uploading-saving-videos-to-database-or-file-system

Comment: @Borgan Fofanov Thank you but I already tried that, it works perfectly in uploading image but uploading video is not working.